# MVC: Application URL doesn't update on page navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-9

In our MVC 4 application, there is an intermittent issue in Internet Explorer 9 where page navigation does not update the browser URL. This seems to happen when the navigation is due to a controller method using return View(...) for the navigation.

This has only been seen twice and both times in IE9, but the fact that's it's happened more than once lead me to believe it might be a problem with our code.

Has anyone else seen/experienced this or have a cause? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try using return JsonResult with Ajax Hope It could help
in your Controller

```
 JsonResult jr=new JsonResult();
 jr.DatarequestBehavior=jr.DatarequestBehavior.AllowGet;
  jr.Data="Something";



        $.Ajax({
          .....
          .....
         ....
       success:function(response){

               window.location("/ Your Controller/Action");
        }
```

});

My Syntax may be Wrong

Comment: View and JsonResult are not even remotely similar.  View returns a full page while JsonResult returns an Ajax snippet.  The issue is surrounding a full blown link click that fails to update the URL parameter.  The link is clicked and forces a URL change via window.location.href... the page changes but no representation of the change is manifested in the location bar.  Thus -1...